# javascript the for loop the increment value does not work

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to make the value of the number if it is divisible by 6

Do something and every condition is success add the number to the increment whose m is the increment of the for loop I am trying to do it but the value m does not increment it, it, only when I make console.log to check it, returns only 1 please help

here is my code

```js
function totalCups(number) {
  for (var m = 1; m <= number; m++) {
    console.log(m++);
    if (number % 6 === 0) {
      return (number / 6) * (6) + m;
    } else {
      return 'this number cant be divide';
    }
  }
}
console.log(totalCups(12));
```

I want to make the first 6 add 1 example 6 + 1

another example 12 + 2

18 + 3
the value of m increment adds 1 and so on

Comment: You've got `m++` twice in the loop. Worse, your `if` statement will always `return`, which will exit the loop immediately.

Comment: Also if `number %6` is 0, then `number/6 *6` is always going to be `number`, so there's no need for the math.

Comment: The `if` condition doesn't depend on `m`, so it doesn't change. Why is it in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

you use return keyword so the if statement become true the execution terminate once execution only.
you can use like this

```js
function totalCups(number) {
  for (var m = 1; m <= number; m++) {
    if (number % 6 === 0) {
      console.log((number / 6) * (6) + m);
    } else {
      return 'this number cant be divide';
    }
  }
}

totalCups(12);
```